# How to fetch the current logged in user in Mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, httpcontext

Hi i need to fetch the id of the live user and i am able to do it.but the problem arises when i switch from one Port to another it does not fetch the user on another port

I have done this:

```
public static Nullable<int> GetLiveUser()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session[ConstantHelper.LoginAccountID] != null)
        {
            return ((int)HttpContext.Current.Session[ConstantHelper.LoginAccountID]);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

ConstantHelper is a class with LoginAccountID as a property.
Please help me

Answer (score 2):

`HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` or inside a `Controller`, `User.Identity.Name`.

See [`IIdentity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using razor, simply use `@User.Identity.Name` in your view. You might also need to disable anonymous authentication and enable Windows Authentication.